# JavaFXPorts jfxmobile-plugin isn't finding platform specific directories

Tags: java, gradle, javafxports

I have a JavaFX-based interface which I'm trying to build on multiple platforms using JavaFXPorts. Most of the code is platform-independent, but I have some utilities that call platform-specific code, e.g. for file system locations on Android vs desktop. For example, in the MCVE below: building with `gradle desktop` or `gradle android`, I get:

```
src/main/java/com/example/project/MyApp.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        platformGreeting = new Label("hello, " + Util.getPlatform());
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable Util
  location: class MyScene
```

But if I put both source files (`MyApp.java` and `Util.java`) together in any of the source directories (`main`, `desktop`, `android`) and run the corresponding task, it will build.

In the examples I've seen, they always implement a platform-independent interface under `src/main`, then implement it in each of the platform-specific directories, but I don't see why this should be necessary.

```
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── android
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── example
    │               └── project
    │                   └── Util.java
    ├── desktop
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── example
    │               └── project
    │                   └── Util.java
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── project
                        └── MyApp.java
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

mainClassName = 'com.example.project.MyApp'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
}

jfxmobile {
    ios {
        forceLinkClasses = [ 'com.example.project.**.*' ]
    }

    android {
        applicationPackage = 'com.example.project'
    }
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'project'
```

src/main/java/com/example/project/MyApp.java:

```
package com.example.project;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public class MyApp extends Application {
    private Scene scene;

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("MyApp");
        scene = new Scene(new MyScene(), 750, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class MyScene extends Region {
    final Label platformGreeting = new Label("hello, " + Util.getPlatform());

    public MyScene() {
        getChildren().add(platformGreeting);
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(platformGreeting, 0, 0, w, h, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

src/desktop/java/com/example/project/Util.java:

```
package com.example.project;

public final class Util {
    private Util() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static final String getPlatform() {
        return "desktop";
    }
}
```

src/android/java/com/example/project/Util.java:

```
package com.example.project;

public final class Util {
    private Util() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static final String getPlatform() {
        return "android";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way the source sets are defined in JavaFXPorts, `main` is shared by all the platforms, and then each specific package is used by the given platform, i.e. `desktop` only on Desktop.

As `main` code is shared by all platforms, it can't contain specific platform code, and it *doesn't* really know about the platform code that was added to any of the platforms.

This is why you get the compilation exception when trying to add `Util` to `main`.

**Solution 1**

A first approach can be done with `Class.forName(className)`. On runtime, it will try to find the given class in the class path.

So this should initially work:

```
    try {
        Class<?> util = Class.forName("com.example.project.Util");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BasicView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

but then you have a problem: you can't really cast to `Util` in the main package.

One possible solution is just using reflection:

```
    try {
        Class<?> util = Class.forName("com.example.project.Util");
        Object newInstance = util.newInstance();
        Method method = util.getDeclaredMethod("getPlatform");
        String platform = (String) method.invoke(newInstance);
        System.out.println("Platform: " + platform));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BasicView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Where I modified `Util` for convenience:

```
public class Util {

    public Util() {
    }

    public final String getPlatform() {
        return "desktop";
    }
}
```

While this works perfectly fine, it is not very easy to work with.

**Solution 2**

So let's add some neutral API to the `main` package, something that we can call more easily: an interface with our method of interest:

```
public interface Platform {

    String getPlatform();
}
```

and now let's implement it in our platform classes:

```
public class Util implements Platform {

    public Util() {
    }

    @Override
    public final String getPlatform() {
        return "desktop";
    }
}
```

Now things get easier, as now you can get a `Platform` instance, and call `getPlatform()`:

```
    try {
        Class<?> util = Class.forName("com.gluonhq.forname.Util");
        Platform platform = (Platform) util.newInstance();
        System.out.println("Platform: " + platform.getPlatform());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BasicView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

**Solution 3: Charm Down**

Charm Down is an [open source library](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/overview) that provides different native services, with a neutral API that can be used from the `main` package, on top of the required platform specific code (Java for Desktop, Android or Objective-C for iOS).

Using the Gluon plugin for your IDE, and creating a project that makes use of the `jfxmobile` plugin will include a few of the services included in Charm Down, as you can see in the `build.gradle` file:

```
jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.7.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    ...
}
```

If you have a look at how these services are implemented, there is a core plugin with several [classes](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/11c36e187921b2eac4a3d518cc00ad9108cab89f/plugins/core/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/?at=default):

- `Platform`
- `Services`
- `ServicesFactory`...

Now on your project, if you include Charm Down dependencies, you can make use of `Platform.getCurrent().name()`.

```
System.out.println("Platform: " + Platform.getCurrent().name());
```

Not only that, you can get any service just with this:

```
Services.get(DisplayService.class)
            .ifPresent(display -> System.out.println("Resolution: " + display.getScreenResolution()));
```

I'd suggest you have a look at how these classes are implemented. And check the different services [available](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/charm-down/) so you don't implement them again. Many of the samples available [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples) make use of one or more of those services.

And if you want to implement a new one, I'd suggest you have a look at the `Go Native` sample ([code](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/go-native) and [tutorial](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/)).